# Sqlite3 stores string as hexadecimal

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

In a Ruby script I need to read some values from an existing g SQLite3 database.

```
DB = SQLite3::Database.open "#{App.root}/db/dm4sea_#{App.env}.db"
```

The database has 1 table (batches) with the following structure

```
DB.execute "PRAGMA table_info(batches);"
=> [[0, "batch", "VARCHAR(30)", 0, nil, 1], 
   [1, "fdl", "INT", 0, nil, 0], 
   [2, "created_at", "DATETIME", 0, nil, 0], 
   [3, "updated_at", "DATETIME", 0, nil, 0]]
```

The current content is

```
DB.execute "SELECT * FROM batches"
=> [["TTX1", 0, "2018-02-20 10:26:17 +0100", "2018-02-20 10:26:17 +0100"], 
    ["TTX2", 0, "2018-02-20 10:36:33 +0100", "2018-02-20 10:36:33 +0100"], 
    ["TTX3", 0, "2018-02-20 10:39:52 +0100", "2018-02-20 10:39:52 +0100"]]
```

However, with my big surprise, the following happens

```
DB.execute "SELECT * FROM batches WHERE batch = 'TTX3'"
=> []
```

Here the database dump

```
sqlite> .dump
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE batches (
          batch VARCHAR(30) PRIMARY KEY,
          fdl INT,
          created_at DATETIME,
          updated_at DATETIME
        );
INSERT INTO batches VALUES(X'54545831',0,'2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100','2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100');
INSERT INTO batches VALUES(X'54545832',0,'2018-02-20 11:40:54 +0100','2018-02-20 11:40:54 +0100');
INSERT INTO batches VALUES(X'54545833',0,'2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100','2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100');
CREATE INDEX batches_batch
        ON batches (batch);
CREATE INDEX batches_fdl
        ON batches (fdl);
COMMIT;
```

Why are the batches stored as hexadecimal values?

```
DB.execute "SELECT * FROM batches WHERE batch = X'54545833'"
=> [["TTX3", 0, "2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100", "2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100"]]
```

Comment: i've created a similar schema and tried - no surprise happened. please add your [sql dump](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-dump/), maybe there is something I can not not populate.

Comment: @marmeladze I have dded it in my post. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

These values are *not* stored as hexadecimal, they are stored as blobs. In SQL statements, the only way to write a blob is with a [blob literal](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#hexint), in which the blob's bytes are represented with hexadecimal digits.

Whatever program wrote the database wrote these values as blobs.

To search for a blob, convert your search value into a blob:

```sql
SELECT * FROM batches WHERE batch = CAST('TTX3' AS BLOB);
```

Alternatively, modify the database so that it contains text values (which might break that other program):

```sql
UPDATE batches SET batch = CAST(batch AS TEXT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm not sure why they were written as blobs, anyway I have re-written the INSERT query and now everything seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

X prefix converts HEX values to strings.

```
sqlite> SELECT X'41';
A
sqlite> SELECT X'42';
B
sqlite> SELECT X'4242';
BB
sqlite> SELECT X'54545831';
TTX1 # Do not forget this one
sqlite> SELECT X'54';
T
sqlite> SELECT X'58';
X
```

Not let's see your code,

```
sqlite> select * from batches;
TTX1|0|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100
TTX2|0|2018-02-20 11:40:54 +0100|2018-02-20 11:40:54 +0100
TTX3|0|2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100|2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100
```

Below queries returns empty sets.

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM batches WHERE batch = 'TTX1';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM batches WHERE batch = 'TTX2';
sqlite> SELECT * FROM batches WHERE batch = 'TTX3';
```

Not insert ordinary string data.

```
sqlite> INSERT INTO batches VALUES('TTX2',0,'2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100','2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100');
sqlite> select * from batches;
TTX1|0|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100
TTX2|0|2018-02-20 11:40:54 +0100|2018-02-20 11:40:54 +0100
TTX3|0|2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100|2018-02-20 11:41:02 +0100
TTX2|0|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100
sqlite> select * from batches where batch = 'TTX2';
TTX2|0|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100|2018-02-20 11:40:46 +0100
```

let's check some equalities.

```
sqlite> Select 123 = 123;
1
sqlite> Select X'54545831' = 'TTX1';
0
```

The data which responds to `batch = TTX{number}` are the ones which you inserted as strings. But the others do not met that condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you are trying to    tell me. Why my strings are stored as hex?

Comment: Your strings are not stored as hex, you are instructing those numeric strings to be handled as hex. `X'{hex_literal}'` takes given as hex and converts them to string.